# How do I deploy my Feathers/Express app to Nginx/Ubuntu?

Tags: express, feathersjs

Like it says on the tin, I'm trying to deploy an app I built on Feathers to my Ubuntu 15 server running Nginx. I'm not finding any straight-forward tutorials online so I thought I'd ask here. I've installed `pm2` and know how to get that running, but my app points to `:3030` by default. I don't know how to get it to point to my homepage.

EDIT: I figured it out myself, but x_maras also has the right answer. I'm using SSL as well, so I had to add `listen 443 ssl;` to my configuration (along with other SSL parameters).

Comment: Are you able to please share how you got your app running on "localhost:3030" using PM2. I'm having troubles getting that to work "npm start" works fine... just not pm2 despite having status "online".

Comment: Got it working, using the config file (for future reference)

module.exports = {
  apps : [

    // First application
    {
      name      : "API",
      script    : "/opt/www/feathersklosa",
      env: {
        COMMON_VARIABLE: "true"
      },
      env_production : {
        NODE_ENV: "production"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that on your nginx configuration with a proxy
e.g.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
}
```

Check the link here https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Oh I figured out the answer and forgot to update my post.